# One of elasticsearch node keep going to error state

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run an elastic search cluster of 2 nodes, but one of the nodes keeps going to Error state while other node working perfectly fine. Below are the logs

```
Kubernetes version 1.16.1
elasticsearch version elasticsearch-oss:6.4.3

es-cluster-0                                   1/1     Running   0          66s

es-cluster-1                                   0/1     Error     2          66s
```

```
[ERROR][o.e.g.GatewayMetaState   ] [es-cluster-1] failed to read local state, exiting...
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: java.io.IOException: failed to read [id:3, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/indices/00hAD3unTn-m80CsNnk5YA/_state/state-3.st]
        at org.elasticsearch.ExceptionsHelper.maybeThrowRuntimeAndSuppress(ExceptionsHelper.java:200) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.loadLatestState(MetaDataStateFormat.java:304) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaStateService.loadFullState(MetaStateService.java:64) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.gateway.GatewayMetaState.<init>(GatewayMetaState.java:86) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:447) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:256) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:213) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:213) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:326) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:127) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) [elasticsearch-cli-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-cli-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:86) [elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed to read [id:3, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/indices/00hAD3unTn-m80CsNnk5YA/_state/state-3.st]
        at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.loadLatestState(MetaDataStateFormat.java:298) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        ... 14 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected field [mapping_version]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexMetaData$Builder.fromXContent(IndexMetaData.java:1324) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexMetaData$2.fromXContent(IndexMetaData.java:1372) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexMetaData$2.fromXContent(IndexMetaData.java:1361) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.read(MetaDataStateFormat.java:196) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.loadLatestState(MetaDataStateFormat.java:294) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
        ... 14 more
```

Comment: can you please share yaml file config so that can verify if any configuration mistake there.

Answer (score 1):

This index was created or modified by Elasticsearch version 6.5.0 or later, and cannot be read in this version any more. This is usually because you upgraded Elasticsearch and then tried to downgrade it again. Downgrades are not possible.

The simplest solution is to continue with the upgrade. If that's not possible, you will need to wipe this node and start again, restoring any lost data from a recent snapshot.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I fixed the issue by deleting the indices in /var/lib/docker/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/ in all worker nodes and its working fine now. Basically the indices created by upgraded version will not able to read by the downgraded version of Elasticsearch.

Comment: I don't think that works in general, but it sounds like you got lucky. It certainly would not have helped in more recent versions.